# How do I unnest an array 2x2 within cells of a column in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that in one its column there are 2x2 np.arrays within each cell. I'm trying to extract these arrays to merge with the original Dataframe.

Suppose I have the following df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[101, 202],'B':[ [[1,2], [3,4]] ,[[5,6], [7,8]] ] })
```

and I need to transform this df into something like this:

```
A, B_1, B_2
101, 1, 2
101, 3, 4
202, 5, 6
202, 7, 8
```

Any suggestions on how can I accomplish this? I've seen other suggestions on how to unnest columns but it only works for 1-dimensional array and not for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
df  =df.set_index('A').B.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'B'})
df1 =pd.DataFrame(df.B.values.tolist()).add_prefix('B_')
pd.concat([df['A'], df1], axis = 1)
```

Comment: `apply(pd.Series)` - it is slow, dont use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with `concat` for DataFrames from `B` column:

```
dcomp = {k:pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in df.pop('B').items()}
df1 = (pd.concat(dcomp)
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x+1)
         .add_prefix('B_'))

df = df.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     A  B_1  B_2
0  101    1    2
1  101    3    4
2  202    5    6
3  202    7    8
```